# Why is my score on this tag less than it should be?

Tags: support, tagging, score

I have just noticed in my profile that my [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) score is given as $36$. However, when I click on the tag, it takes me to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:736802+%5Bcalculus%5D) link, which shows all my posts (questions and answers) tagged [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus). When I individually calculated the score, it came out to be $46$ instead of $36$.

I think I have not correctly understood how the score for a tag is counted. But **how is it done?**

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Explain tag numbers in profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73164) and [Wrong number associated with specific Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353807).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That link may be a bit misleading, as it lists all your posts in that tag (currently 28, and that number is also shown in the profile).

For the [tag score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/295232), **only non-Community Wiki *answers* count**. A better explanation is given on the [tags tab of your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/736802/sai-kartik?tab=tags), if you hover over the score:

[image]

[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A736802+%5Bcalculus%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ano) lists all posts which are relevant for the score; it's obtained by adding the search terms `is:answer wiki:no`.

[image]

Comment: Unless I've modified the search query incorrectly, I have no [c.w answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A736802+%5Bcalculus%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ayes) or [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A736802+%5Bcalculus%5D+is%3Aquestion+wiki%3Ayes)..

Comment: @sai-kartik Questions don't count for the tag score, whether CW or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer ahh that explains a lot...